# Background photo in header CSS when loading page before scrolling down

Tags: css, html, static, header

I'm designing a template-based [website](http://sitiosimple.com/interlock/#!/-rubes-landscaping/). My service provider allows me to include CSS or HTML in head and body of the root site.

I tried the header to show the photo in the background ([sample](https://www.robertlandscapes.com/)) when loading the page but it wasn't possible. It moves it to the a section below. Once scrolling down it's finally seen behind in the background. I tried transparency but that's not the solution. I tried a photo top margin -370px and other things but both sections don't work in the initial position after loading and befor scrolling.

1. Any idea of how to show the background photo when the page loads and is in static position before scrolling down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Andres

It is not clear to me what is it you are trying to achieve, neither with your example nor with your own site.

A) you want the background photo to be seen AT ALL TIMES, regardless of where you are scrolling?

Comment: Hi Sotkra. Thanks for replying. I edited my post and this comment. I want that when the page loads there's no blank space in the background but the photo. Right now the photo moves below the white space automatically in the initial position. Then when you scroll down, the page jumps and the photo appears in the background suddenly (I'm using -370px for the photo's top margin). Hope I wasn't confusing but I haven't been able to find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Then call the photo using background:url(myimage.jpg) no-repeat scroll center center transparent; and then add background-size:cover or contain depending on the intended result (and the proportions of your image).

Answer (score 0):

your question is a bit unclear..

i think what you are trying to say is when they scroll down you want the nav-bar to move-to-top in a static approach..

apply z-index property and position to static

Comment: Hi DAMMAK. Thanks for replying. I edited my post and this comment. I want that when the page loads there's no blank space in the background but the photo. Right now the photo moves below the white space automatically in the initial position. Then when you scroll down, the page jumps and the photo appears in the background suddenly (I'm using -370px for the photo's top margin). Hope I wasn't confusing but I haven't been able to find a solution. Thanks!